# Windows Background randomly updates to green

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop, external-display

If my desktop somehow updates, the wallpaper gets replaced with green color. That looks like this: [image]
If I right-click and do “Refresh”, the whole background gets green.

I think that has something to do with the second monitor connected to my Laptop. Also, all my drivers are up-to-date, and I run the latest Windows version.

The bug happens at random intervals and I have no idea why.

*More information on request.*

Comment: It hurts in the eyes compared to the dark background I usually have.

Comment: Oops, I may write that wrong. Thanks, but that has nothing to do with the main problem.

Comment: What picture format is your desktop image? If it's png, try re-saving it as jpg.

Comment: It's a jpg file.

Comment: OK. There goes my theory then ;)

Comment: And what's your theory?

Comment: Stray alpha/transparency channel - can't happen with jpg.

Comment: But it looks like that's exactly what's happening with my wallpaper.

Comment: jpg doesn't have alpha.

Comment: So what is the solution now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the icon cache got corrupted somehow.

Navigate to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`

replace %username% with your username.

Here you will see a lot of files like iconcache_32.db, iconcache_48.db, iconcache_96.db, iconcache_256.db, iconcache_1024.db, iconcache_1280.db, iconcache_1600.db, iconcache_1920.db, iconcache_2560.db, iconcache_exif.db, iconcache_idx.db, iconcache_sr.db, iconcache_wide.dd, iconcache_wide_alternate.db, etc.

Delete them all to purge and rebuild your icon cache in Windows 10. If you were to be able to delete some of them, you would now be able to see a new folder created named IconcacheToDelete, which will disappear when you reboot your computer or restart Windows File Explorer.

[source](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-icon-clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-10) (note it also includes a DOS method if the above does not work.